# Problem with datasource-identification. Delete elements in another list with a workflow

Tags: 2013, list, workflow, data

My Situation:

I have two Worfkflows(List)
[image]

I have two Lists
[image]
"Genehmigung" is the tasklist for the workflow
"Teamkalender" is the calender

I have a calender who everybody can use in my company.
 So if someone create a Element, it starts a workflow which assign a task to a specific person. This assignment create a Element in the workflow-tasklist(Genehmigungen).

Now i created the Button "Stornieren" in the Displayformular for the Calender elements. This Button starts another Workflow which should delete the Element in my tasklist(Genehmigungen). I use "delete item in THIS list" because it is the other list.

My Problem is, that i dont know which field i can use for the datasource-identification

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on THIS LIST link you'll get **all the lists in the site**.
Later of course you need to identify the record in the other list.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean? I dont understand.

Comment: If - when you are in SPD in the WF - you choose "delete", you get "this list" linked. Clicking on this link opens a popup window with a selector, by default on "Current item". If you click on "current item" you'll have a list of options and all lists in the site available there.

Comment: Yeah. But if i a choose another List, i must identify my Element and thats the Problem. There are a lot of Elements in the other List. so yeah i must identify which element from the other list i need. But how!?

Comment: Of course you need some data to hook it. I can imagine there is some logic that ties the data in the current list and its correspondent to be deleted. Otherwise you have to use a manual input creating a parameter (Initiation from parameter) which will prompt user to give the data you need.